# How does sorting on enums actually work?

Tags: mysql, sql, enums, sql-order-by

I am experiencing some odd behavior when running the following query in MySQL command line client:

```
SELECT favoriteGenre, firstName, lastName 
FROM members 
ORDER BY favoriteGenre, firstName;
```

I get the following results:

```
favoriteGenre       firstName       lastName
crime               Jane            Field
crime               John            Sparks
horror              Marty           Pareene
thriller            Mary            Newton
romance             Jo              Scrivener
sciFi               Nick            Blakeley
nonFiction          Bill            Swan
```

Yet I was expecting these results:

```
favoriteGenre       firstName       lastName
crime               Jane            Field
crime               John            Sparks
horror              Marty           Pareene
nonFiction          Bill            Swan
romance             Jo              Scrivener
sciFi               Nick            Blakeley
thriller            Mary            Newton
```

Note that `nonFiction` is in the 7th position, while I expected it to be 4th...

This the SQL used to create the table:

```
USE mydatabase;

CREATE TABLE members (
  id              SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username        VARCHAR(30) BINARY NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password        CHAR(41) NOT NULL,
  firstName       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  lastName        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  joinDate        DATE NOT NULL,
  gender          ENUM( 'm', 'f' ) NOT NULL,
  favoriteGenre   ENUM( 'crime', 'horror', 'thriller', 'romance', 'sciFi', 'adventure', 'nonFiction' ) NOT NULL,
  emailAddress    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  otherInterests  TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO members VALUES( 1, 'sparky', password('mypass'), 'John', 'Sparks', '2007-11-13', 'm', 'crime', 'jsparks@example.com', 'Football, fishing and gardening' );
INSERT INTO members VALUES( 2, 'mary', password('mypass'), 'Mary', 'Newton', '2007-02-06', 'f', 'thriller', 'mary@example.com', 'Writing, hunting and travel' );
INSERT INTO members VALUES( 3, 'jojo', password('mypass'), 'Jo', 'Scrivener', '2006-09-03', 'f', 'romance', 'jscrivener@example.com', 'Genealogy, writing, painting' );
INSERT INTO members VALUES( 4, 'marty', password('mypass'), 'Marty', 'Pareene', '2007-01-07', 'm', 'horror', 'marty@example.com', 'Guitar playing, rock music, clubbing' );
INSERT INTO members VALUES( 5, 'nickb', password('mypass'), 'Nick', 'Blakeley', '2007-08-19', 'm', 'sciFi', 'nick@example.com', 'Watching movies, cooking, socializing' );
INSERT INTO members VALUES( 6, 'bigbill', password('mypass'), 'Bill', 'Swan', '2007-06-11', 'm', 'nonFiction', 'billswan@example.com', 'Tennis, judo, music' );
INSERT INTO members VALUES( 7, 'janefield', password('mypass'), 'Jane', 'Field', '2006-03-03', 'f', 'crime', 'janefield@example.com', 'Thai cookery, gardening, traveling' );
```

What is really going on behind the scenes, and how is this sorting being done? Is this behavior unique only to MySQL?

Comment: It's a very odd result...

Comment: It really should be doing what you're expecting it's doing. Is there something going on with capital letters or whitespace or such?

Comment: Please post the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE members`. Ordering is dependent on a table or column's collation, and something strange is happening with `favoriteGenre`.

Comment: Could you prove that result using sqlfiddle? or even phpmyadmin screenshot?

Comment: It is also possible that the errant values have some non-printable character at the start, causing them to sort out of place. You may check `SELECT DISTINCT favoriteGenre, LENGTH(favoriteGenre) FROM members` to verify that the length is correct.

Comment: it is an enum what you are sorting

Comment: Okay everyone, good news. Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b3d2/1) with OP's update that **DOES NOT** produce expected results. Maybe someone will find it before I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`favoriteGenre` is an `enum`, and not a text field as most of us was expecting to see.

As you can read in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html#enum-sorting), `enum`s are sorted on their index, not on their textual representation. That makes the outcome of your query correct.

To sort an `enum` by its value, you need to use `CAST(col AS CHAR)` (thanks [McAdam331](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3131147/mcadam331) for adding this, also see his [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b3d2/2)). I would advise though to do proper normalization on your database.

Comment: I would add that to sort an enum by its value, you need to use `CAST(col AS CHAR`) as seen by [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b3d2/2). If you want to add it to your answer go ahead, and I can delete my comment.

Comment: Thank you @PatrickHofman, solution actually works but please if possible explain how normalization would help in this case.

Comment: Of course. If you separate your 'label' (the enum text) from your 'id' (the enum index), you can sort on what you prefer. It is also possible to add more columns on `genre` if you need to, which isn't possible now.

Comment: @McAdam331: Thanks. I added it. Keep your comment so people know you were the source of all this good ;).

Comment: @PatrickHofman sure. I was mostly referring to adding the Fiddle link to your answer, but if people don't want to read the comments it's their loss ;)

Answer (score 3):

It will first sort the results by first column , And if there is more than one result in one type , In your case it is crime ; It will sort on the basis of 2nd defined column.

So first it will sort favoriteGenre and then by first name

Your case it is enum , So it changes the entire game. It will only sort related to it's index. Hence you are getting such odd behavior.

Hope it explains

Comment: Yes, this is correct to the broader question of how sorting works, however if you look closely at their returned results against the results they expect (like you've explained) you'll see that that isn't happen.

Comment: Indeed. `nonFiction` shouldn't be at the end. That is where the question is about.

Comment: @McAdam331 you should have explained datatypes earlier to understand problem. However now I know where the problem was

Comment: The datatypes were not there when I wrote my initial comment, the OP edited the question afterward. I apologize for the confusion, I myself was in the dark.

Comment: Since vishal updated his post to be clearer, I voted it up so it would not appear as a negative vote and confuse future readers, as the answer is now correct :)

Comment: @nomistic / vishal - I never meant to be rude and say that it was 'incorrect'. His initial thoughts were completely valid, but there was a lot more going on in the question. I wasn't the one who gave it a downvote, I just wanted to point out that what *should* happen wasn't what *was* happening.